# BCP Utility - omit default values in import file

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EXTRACT](
    ID int IDENTITY,
    CREATE_DTTM datetime default GETDATE() NOT NULL,
    CONTRACT_ID varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    EXCEPTION_REASON varchar(max),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID ASC)
);
```

And a source file that only supplies columns 3, 4 and 5.  Below is my XML format file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="12"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="24"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="ID" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="CREATE_DTTM" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="CONTRACT_ID" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="ACCOUNT_NUMBER" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="EXCEPTION_REASON" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

which works with this input file:

```
,,contract_2,account_2,exception_reason_2
```

But is it possible to omit the first two fields in the input file to make it like this:

```
contract_2,account_2,exception_reason_2
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-skip-a-table-column-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), remove the `column` rows that you don't want to populate from your format file, and renumber the fields and sources accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="CONTRACT_ID" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="ACCOUNT_NUMBER" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="EXCEPTION_REASON" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

That being said, the safest, cleanest way to do this is to Bulk Import your data into a staging table that is shaped the same as your source file, and then call a procedure that moves the data from your staging table to the final destination table.

Comment: I have deduced the same from the docs yet it does not work.  If I adjust the format file as you have described, I get "Invalid date format" error.  I don't want to use another table shaped like my extract since the target table [EXTRACT] is already a staging table from which rows will be processed and pushed into a "historical" table along with processing result.